# unwanted character appended with each character written by java program

Tags: java

unwanted characters being added to words in text file by following code.
please help how can i resolve it.

```
try
    {
        Fout = new FileOutputStream("C:/IBM/omnibus.txt",true);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(Fout);     
        {
            dos.writeUTF(SitName.getText().toString() + "\t");
            dos.writeUTF(TTGrp.getText().trim() + "\t");
            dos.writeUTF(EmailGrp.getText().trim() + "\t");

            if(chkAlertY.isSelected())
                dos.writeUTF("1 \t");
            if(chkAlertN.isSelected())
                dos.writeUTF("0 \t");

            if(chkSmsY.isSelected())
                dos.writeUTF("1 \t");
            if(chkSmsN.isSelected())
                dos.writeUTF("0 \t");

            if(chkEmailY.isSelected())
                dos.writeUTF("1 \n");
            if(chkEmailN.isSelected())
                dos.writeUTF("0 \n");

            Fout.close();
       }
```

**Output>>**

```
abc  NULETXdef  NUL ETXghi  1
```

---

New code

```
try
        {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter ("C:/IBM/omnibus.txt",true);
        BufferedWriter dos = new BufferedWriter(file);
        dos.write(SitName.getText().toString() + "\t");
        dos.write(TTGrp.getText().trim() + "\t");
        dos.write(EmailGrp.getText().trim() + "\t");

            if(chkAlertY.isSelected())
                dos.write("1 \t");
            if(chkAlertN.isSelected())
                dos.write("0 \t");

            if(chkSmsY.isSelected())
                dos.write("1 \t");
            if(chkSmsN.isSelected())
                dos.write("0 \t");

            if(chkEmailY.isSelected())
                dos.write("1 \n");
            if(chkEmailN.isSelected())
                dos.write("0 \n");

            file.close();

    }

        catch(Exception e)
          {
            System.out.println("The Exception Is : " +e);
          } 
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Did you read the docs for writeUTF, at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String) ?  This probably answers your question.

Comment: what are you trying to do? write to a file, yes, but why are you using writeUTF method if you're writing 1's and 0's?

Answer (score 3):

Use BufferedWriter instead of DataOutputStream. DataOutputStream.writeUTF writes text in special format which is supposed to be read with DataInputStream. Take a look at writeUTF API *... First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow...*

Comment: try some example, like this one http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Comment: @user2720237 close the writer instead of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The output of [`DataOutputStream#writeUTF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) is a special UTF formatted string that is intended to be read by `DataInputStream#readUTF()` method.

The java docs of the `writeUTF` method states about first 2 bytes in written UTF string.

> Writes a string to the underlying output stream using modified UTF-8
>   encoding in a machine-independent manner.
>
> **First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the
>   writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow.** This value is
>   the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the
>   string. Following the length, each character of the string is output,
>   in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character. If
>   no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the
>   total number of bytes written to the output stream. This will be at
>   least two plus the length of str, and at most two plus thrice the
>   length of str.